# How do you set an element by default as collapsed when landing on page? Wix Velo

Tags: velo

I'm doing a FAQ accordion style box elements in Wix, the code I have in Velo works on Desktop, however on Mobile all the collapsible box elements are expanded when landing on the page. How can I have them all be collapsed by default unless clicked on?

```
$w.onReady(function () {

    $w('#aboutUsCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#aboutUsCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#aboutUsPlusSign'), $w('#aboutUsMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#volunteerCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#volunteerCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#volunteerPlusSign'), $w('#volunteerMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#findMissionsCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#findMissionsCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#findMissionsPlusSign'), $w('#findMissionsMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#missionAccomplishedCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#missionAccomplishedCollapsibleStrip'),$w('#missionAccomplishedPlusSign'), $w('#missionAccomplishedMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#agentRankCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#agentRankCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#agentRankPlusSign'), $w('#agentRankMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#agentBriefingRoomCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#agentBriefingRoomCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#agentBriefingRoomPlusSign'), $w('#agentBriefingRoomMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#shopCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#shopCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#shopPlusSign'), $w('#shopMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#giveCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#giveCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#givePlusSign'), $w('#giveMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#contactCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#contactCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#contactPlusSign'), $w('#contactMinusSign'));
    });

    $w('#socialMediaCollapseButton').onClick(() => {
    toggleBox($w('#socialMediaCollapsibleStrip'), $w('#socialMediaPlusSign'), $w('#socialMediaMinusSign'));
    });
});



function toggleBox(boxElement, plusSign, minusSign) {

    const isCollapsed = boxElement.collapsed;
        if (isCollapsed) {
        plusSign.hide();
        minusSign.show();
        boxElement.expand();
    } else {
        minusSign.hide();
        plusSign.show();
        boxElement.collapse();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the collapsed setting in the Properties & Events panel is per device type. So you need to open your site in the mobile editor and set the strips to be collapsed there as well.

Alternatively, instead of setting the collapsed value in the P&E panel, you could write code to collapse all of the sections as the page loads. That should work on desktop and mobile.

Using your naming conventions, and assuming you're using column strips, you could do something like this:

```
const strips = $w('ColumnStrip');
const collapsibleStrips = strips.filter(strip => strip.id.endsWith('CollapsibleStrip'));
collapsibleStrips.forEach(strip => strip.collapse());
```

Of course, you can refactor this code to work with other naming conventions and types of elements.